# Symbols render fine in Eclipse Debug mode, but print incorrectly

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, character-encoding

I'm trying to extract the correct currency Symbol from an excel cell using JExcel. I think I've cracked it.

When I look in the variables tab, in the debug perspective, I see this:

`currencySymbol|€`

When I print it out however, I get either a ?, or a series of other character depending on the charset I use.

Why is it displayed ok in the debug window, but it won't appear when printed to the console?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/342392/1075247)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue for the € symbol, and many others, but it's still displaying the £ sign <strike>a black hexagon with a central question mark</strike> [Replacement Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character#Replacement_character).

I solved the issue with the € by setting the console output of eclipse to UTF-8.

`Project MenuBar -> Properties -> ResourceTab -> Text File Encoding ->Other ComboBox -> UTF-8`